# Not able to convert alphanumeric to string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to python.I am working on Amazon Alexa. In that I am passing a session attribute like this

```
token = 2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043
session_attributes = {"Token":token}
```

This token contains data in alpha numeric i.e the id got from rest API.
On the next function where I am passing it, it should be added in REST API header such as:

```
 headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X--Application-Id': '5gdwgjb7788e5466c27e33e40',
    'X--User-token': '2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043'
    }
```

When I am passing the token, variable is not working. How I can send the token as string in the header:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X--Application-Id': '5gdwgjb7788e5466c27e33e40',
    'X--User-token': token
    }
```

Comment: `token = 2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043` is not valid python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `token = 2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043` is not valid python.

Try `token = '2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043'` instead.

Comment: on token = '2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043' its working but i am getting token as  2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043 how to save it as '2nc87nlcnclbihiuh882222a5ac4b043'

Comment: use `token = str(token_variable)`